# Open Layers - GeoJSON bad projection

Tags: openlayers, geojson, projection

I have a problem when loading a GeoJSON like that:

```
new OlLayerVector({
    source: new OlSourceVector({
           url: layer.url,
           format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({defaultDataProjection: dataProjection, featureProjection})
    })
});
```

the loaded features are badly possitioned and way too big, despite specifing the projection which is EPSG:32632.

When I load the json locally then everything is displayed correctly:

```
new OlLayerVector({
    source: new OlSourceVector({
           features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geoJsonData, {dataProjection, featureProjection});
    })
});

Any ideas?
```

Comment: Which version of OpenLayers are you using?  `defaultDataProjection`:was changed to `dataProjection`: in version 5.

Comment: That was it. Using `dataProjection` works. But it's weird, cause when looking at the interface its: 
`interface GeoJSONOptions {
            defaultDataProjection: ol.ProjectionLike;
            featureProjection: ol.ProjectionLike;
            geometryName?: string;
        }
`

I've added a `//@ts-ignore` cause it's prevent me from building the app